# laravel-how to send an email that contain a div with background-image from my server to gmail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

When i send an email from my server to gmail, background- image does not show in gmail.

this is my code :

```
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="float: right;">
            <div class="mahd-logo" style=" background-image: url('{{ asset('/uploads/mahdLogo/' . $mahdLogo) }}');">


            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="float: left;">

            <div class="mahd-logo" style=" background-image: url('/img/kindino_mailLogo.png');"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and the controller is like this:

```
  $data = array('id' => $activity['id'], 'type' => "activity",'parent'=>$staticRelationship,'teacher'=>$staticfromTeacher,'title'=>$title,'msg' => $staticComment,'mahdPhone'=>$mahdNumber,'mahdLogo'=>$mahdLogo);

if($email) {
                                $path='/img/kindino_mailLogo.png';
                                \Mail::send('pages.mail', $data, function ($message) use ($mahd, $title, $email, $request) {
                                    $message->from('kindinoteam@gmail.com', "مهدکودک - $mahd->mahdName");
                                    $message->to($email)->subject($title)
                                    ->attach(public_path($path));
                                });
                            }
```

but when i open gmail, it does not show any image. how can i fix it?

Comment: Are you getting this image as attachment with the email?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal yes,this image is dynamic in my server, but it send as a logo in email. and it is a background-image for a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `table` approach in creating email template. try this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="background_image.png">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Content on a pretty background image.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is a [guide](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email) in adding background images in email template